# Python Regular Expression Grouping Assistance Please

Tags: python, regex

I am attempting to join two fields together in one findall and print all the results.

```
a = ['Name: Donut,
      PUL: 21392132,
      Quantity: 7,
      Name: Red Donut,
      PUL: 25,
      Quantity :25'
      ]

d = .join(re.findall(r'\bquantity.(.*)+\bname.(.*)', a)
print(d)
e = re.findall(r'\bname.(.*)', a)
```

The desired result should be similar to the below

25 x Red Donut
7 x Donut

I am able to pick up the name or quantity separately by using the below command

```
e = re.findall(r'\bname.(.*)', a)
```

However, when I try to join them together I keep getting empty results or error messages.

Any assistance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There's a syntax error. ```input()``` is a function you cannot ```input[]```

Comment: See https://ideone.com/m8zSq5, it what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

First restructure the data into a multi-line string, then create patterns for quantities and names (while setting the re.I, i.e. the re.IGNORECASE-flag), reverse the results, and finally join them into one result string:

```
import re

a = """
Name: Donut,
PUL: 21392132,
Quantity: 7,
Name: Red Donut,
PUL: 25,
Quantity: 25
"""

quantities_pattern = re.compile(r"\bquantity:\s(\d+)", re.I)
quantities_reverse = re.findall(quantities_pattern, a)[::-1]
print(quantities_reverse)

names_pattern = re.compile(r"\bname:\s(\w+\s?\w*),", re.I)
names_reverse = re.findall(names_pattern, a)[::-1]
print(names_reverse)

lines = []
for qty, name in zip(quantities_reverse, names_reverse):
    lines.append(qty + ' x ' + name + ' ')

print(''.join(lines))
```

Result:

```
['25', '7']
['Red Donut', 'Donut']
25 x Red Donut 7 x Donut
```

Or if you want the results line-by-line:

```
for line in lines:
    print(line)
```

Returning:

```
25 x Red Donut 
7 x Donut
```